# Sending information to a webservice through SOAP

Tags: soap

I want to send data from a user form to a Mailing service called Doppler, they gave me a confusing documentation ( www.fromdoppler.com/resources/Doppler_API_Technical_Documentation.pdf ) about connecting to its webservice, i've tried to send the information via jQuery but I get the Cross-Domain Error.

Can you please help by telling me how should I connect to the webservice and send data from a form?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use JSONP. You can see this page.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: I can't use JSNOP (i think), because Doppler requests me an XML. :(